# 22nd straight day on week- on- week gains

Tags: meaning-in-context

Tokyo alone recorded 614 new cases on Sunday, **the
22nd straight day of week-on-week gains**.

What did **the 22nd straight day of week-on-week gains** mean?

What is the 22nd straight day?
straight have much meaning in the dictionary, but I cannot know which is this straight mean. Is 22nd mean the twenty-second? How can a day be straight? Also, the week-on-week make me confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the seven days to Sunday there were more cases than there were in the seven days to the previous Sunday (week-on-week means 'a week compared to the previous week').

This is also true for the week to Saturday compared to the week up to the previous Saturday, and likewise back for the preceding 22 days (the week to Friday, Thursday, Wednesday, etc). This was the 22nd consecutive ('straight') day that this was true.